# div doesn't take the whole height / is not 100%

Tags: html, css

here is the live link: http://mrgsp.md:8080/a/Account/SignIn

the main div (green one) doesn't take 100% of the screen height

you will notice this only if you have a big screen[image]

and the code is basically

```
<body>
<div class="loginpage">
<div id="loginbox">stuff inside loginbox</div>
</div>
</body>

.loginpage {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
padding:200px;
}
```

Comment: FYI - I can't view the page.  Is it on an intranet or is port 8080 closed?  Maybe post a screenshot and also post just the code in question.

Comment: ok, probably it's limited to my country only, I'll post a screenshot and code

Comment: Why would it? It has the height of its inner div + its own padding.

Also, why don't you put the green background onto the body element? Then it will color all the page (and I guess that's your problem, right?).

Comment: @Michael La Voie I've added screenshot and code

Comment: @Shautieh yes setting the color to the body also could be a solution; is it not possible to set height of a div to be 100% of the available height ? just like a table with height = 100% would do it

Comment: @Omu : because it only takes enough vertical space to contain what's inside. In your case the inner div plus its own padding, border and margin => you have the impression it works for smaller screens, but that's only because you have 800px of vertical padding set on this div.

Comment: About height=100%, you would need to set it on every container from the div up to the html tag, but even then it may result in so-so results depending on the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for my English...

put the background style in body... is better.

```css
body{
    background: green;
}
```

If you still want to put a height for the div, you must put 100% height for the div, for the body, and for HTML too.

```css
html, body, .loginpage{
    height: 100% ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the body the green background color?

Comment: Or if for some reason you need the inner div to be green and body to still be white:

html,body{
height:100%;
}
#main-container{
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply set a div height to 100%, because [it will interpret that as 100% of its container](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/200.htm).

The simplest solution to your problem is to set the background color on the body element, but alternatively, you can use your method by setting the body tag to have a height of 100%.  This will give your div something to fill fully.  If the body or whatever container of the div doesn't have a height set, then the browser defaults the css property of the div to height: auto.